# Bootable ISO from GCP snapshot - how to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot, iso

I have created a VM instance (Ubuntu 20.04) in GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and then installed a couple of required software (Koha, DSpace, Greenstone, Moodle, VuFind) for conducting an online workshop. Is it possible to convert the snapshot of the said VM instance into a bootable iso file so that I can distribute that iso file (pre-configured with a couple of software) for local use (e.g. installation in a laptop/desktop)? Most of the documents I'm getting in public domain talk about creating a VM instance in GCP from custom ISO but not the other way round.

Comment: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/make-your-very-own-customized-linux-distro-from-your-current-installation

Comment: https://www.linux-live.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [procedure](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#create-export-manually) to create a raw disk file from a GCE disk and upload it to Cloud Storage. Then, you can [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) the file from GCS and convert it to ISO format using this [tool](https://github.com/not-a-user/raw2iso).

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a comprehensive answer. Regards ...